# StreamSocketListener port randomly hangs on Windows IoT UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I have a UWP background app that I wrote which runs on a Raspberry Pi running the latest build of Windows IoT.  It's purpose is to handle http requests and return a response to several mobile apps.

It works great, except that it seems like the listening port on the socket will occasionally hang.  The rest of the background app remains responsive so I know the app is still running.  But the http requests stop responding.  Usually just logging into the IoT Dashboard and restarting my app will resolve the problem.  But I can't figure out why the app occasionally hangs.

Here is the segment of code that I think is relevant:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;

namespace MyApp.Sandbox
{
    public class SystemTest : IBackgroundTask
    {
        private StreamSocketListener listener = null;

        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            StartServer();
        }

        public async void StartServer()
        {
            try
            {
                int port = 8189;

                listener = new StreamSocketListener();
                var currentSetting = listener.Control.QualityOfService;
                listener.Control.QualityOfService = SocketQualityOfService.LowLatency;

                await listener.BindServiceNameAsync(port.ToString());

                listener.ConnectionReceived += async (sender, args) =>
                {
                    var request = new StringBuilder();
                    using (var input = args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead())
                    {
                        int maxBuffer = 8192;
                        int index = 0;

                        List<byte> line = new List<byte>();
                        int b;
                        while (true)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                b = input.ReadByte();
                                line.Add((byte)b);

                                if (b == 10 && line.Count >= 2)
                                {
                                    if (line[line.Count - 2] == 13 && line[line.Count - 1] == 10)
                                    {
                                        byte[] byteArray = line.ToArray();
                                        var dataString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                                        request.Append(dataString);
                                        line = new List<byte>();

                                        if (request.ToString().StartsWith("GET"))
                                        {
                                            break;
                                        }

                                        if (request.ToString().StartsWith("POST") &&
                                            request.ToString().Contains(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine))
                                        {
                                            string contentLength = GetValueFromHeader("Content-Length", request.ToString());
                                            if (!contentLength.Equals(""))
                                            {
                                                int length = Convert.ToInt32(contentLength);
                                                if (length > 0)
                                                {
                                                    byteArray = new byte[length];
                                                    input.Read(byteArray, 0, length);
                                                    dataString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                                                    request.Append(dataString);
                                                }
                                            }
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                index++;

                                if (index > maxBuffer)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        input.Dispose();
                    }

                    using (var output = args.Socket.OutputStream)
                    {
                        using (var response = output.AsStreamForWrite())
                        {
                            var requestLines = request.ToString().Split(' ');
                            var url = requestLines.Length > 1 ? requestLines[1] : string.Empty;

                            string postLine = null;
                            if (requestLines.Length > 0)
                            {
                                if (requestLines[0] == "POST")
                                {
                                    postLine = requestLines[requestLines.Length - 1];
                                }
                            }

                            string str = null;
                            try
                            {
                                // handle response here which fills "str"
                            }
                            catch (Exception innerEx)
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine(innerEx.Message);
                                Debug.WriteLine(innerEx.StackTrace);
                            }

                            var html = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
                            using (var bodyStream = new MemoryStream(html))
                            {
                                var header = $"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: {bodyStream.Length}\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\ncharset: UTF-8\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
                                var headerArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
                                await response.WriteAsync(headerArray, 0, headerArray.Length);
                                await bodyStream.CopyToAsync(response);
                                await response.FlushAsync();
                            }
                        }
                        output.Dispose();
                    }
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have confirmed that "Compile with .NET Native Toolchain" is enabled in my build configuration.  And I am running this in release mode.

I am not sure if there is something different I need to be doing to release the incoming connections?  Is it perhaps hanging because multiple requests are coming in at the same time and it can't handle it?

Here is an example of what netstat looks like when the port (in this case it is 8081) hangs:

```
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     5.101.0.209:32880      CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     5.101.0.209:33494      CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     5.101.0.209:60412      CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Mike-PC:59879          CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Mike-PC:59880          CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:43096    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:43110    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:43114    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:43120    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:43130    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:43742    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:43744    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:43750    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:43822    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:43914    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:43986    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:48646    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:48648    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:48702    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:48724    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:48774    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:48776    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:48820    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:48834    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:48918    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:49036    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:49058    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:49284    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:49416    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:49672    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:49680    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:50360    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:50566    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:50718    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:50724    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:50734    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:50938    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:51082    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:51524    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:51880    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:51946    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:52146    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:52212    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:52224    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:52310    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:53126    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:53206    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     Galaxy-S20-5G:53284    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.190:8081     192.227.118.82:1550    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.190:59613    52.242.211.89:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::]:22                myapp:0                LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:135               myapp:0                LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:445               myapp:0                LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:5985              myapp:0                LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:8080              myapp:0                LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:8081              myapp:0                LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:47001             myapp:0                LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49664             myapp:0                LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49665             myapp:0                LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49667             myapp:0                LISTENING
  UDP    0.0.0.0:123            *:*                    
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5050           *:*                    
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*                    
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*                    
  UDP    0.0.0.0:29819          *:*                    
  UDP    0.0.0.0:51049          *:*                    
  UDP    [::]:123               *:*                    
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*                    
  UDP    [::]:5355              *:*
```

At this point I am open to suggestions if anybody else has run into a similar situation....

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to add [StreamSocket.Dispose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket.dispose?view=winrt-17134) Method to abort any pending operations and releases all unmanaged resources associated with the StreamSocket object.

```
            listener.Control.KeepAlive = true;

            listener.ConnectionReceived += async (sender, args) =>
            {
                //Your codes


                args.Socket.Dispose();
            };
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think to check the args.  I made this change and will monitor it over the next few days and see if that prevents the port from locking up.  I will report my results after some time passes...  Thanks so much - hopefully this fixes it!

Comment: Hey Michael - It looks like this did not fix the problem. I woke up this morning and I am not getting a response from that port.  I added netstat to my original question in case there are clues in there that could be helpful. Any other ideas?

Comment: Looking at the netstat I posted above, I see an IP address I don't recognize and it is showing the connection as "ESTABLISHED" where all the other connections are "CLOSE_WAIT".  Is it possible this is some external connection that has been made (from a non-trusting source) and is holding onto the connection so no other connections can be made? If so, is there a way I can force connections like these to timeout after a few seconds?

Comment: @MikeLuken, I have update the code. The property [KeepAlive](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketlistenercontrol.keepalive?view=winrt-18362#Windows_Networking_Sockets_StreamSocketListenerControl_KeepAlive) indicates the StreamSocket object sends keep-alive packets when no data or acknowledgment packets have been received for the TCP connection within an interval.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I have added this property.  So far so good.  I will monitor it for a few days and see if the problem is completely resolved.  I will report back when I know for sure.  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @MikeLuken, may i know how about the testing? If the issue was fixed, please accept it as answer so that it will be helpful for other users who encounters the similar problem.

Comment: So far it hasn't hung yet.  So that is a good 5 days.  I am going to call it fixed.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey Michael. I may have spoken too soon. It is definitely better. But I just implemented a device that uses HTTP to hit that socket about once per second indefinitely. It works great, but it seems like about once per day I am still experiencing this same issue where the socket becomes unresponsive. Can you think of anything else to perhaps add? I could write logic to say if it is unreachable to restart the IoT app automatically, but I would rather find the underlying cause.

Comment: @MikeLuken Did you ever resolve this? I have some devices that stop responding at least once a day. Dispose doesn't seem to work, I can't bind a new listener after the device has gone into this state, only restarting seems to fix it. I am looking for a way to recover without restart